# Google playstore pricing - free or paid?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I am going to publish my first app on google play store. Currently my app is completely free but later on I want to add some in app purchases ( but users should still be able to download it for free).Now how should I set the pricing now - free or paid ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can publish your application for free. You can add in-app purchases with IAP.

> Best practices:
>
> - Make your app available as a free download with limited features or    full features for a limited time. Then use an in-app purchase to
>   unlock the full, unlimited app.
> - Offer additional features or content items through in-app purchases,    such as new levels, special playing pieces, or other
>   features in    games.
> - Use subscriptions where your app provides regularly updated or    time-based content.